# Python Array is out of order when iterating through char array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple Lexer in python to parse some sudo code as a fun side project.

I read a file into a string and convert the string into a char array with `code = list(code)`

The file looks like this:

`print "Hello World";`

The array ends up looking like this:

`code = ['p', 'r', 'i', 'n', 't', ' ', '"', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '"', ';']`

At this point I iterate through it, and append certain characters to an array with the following code:

```
for c in code:
    if c == '(':
        TOKENS.append(Tokens.LPAREN)
    if c == ')':
        TOKENS.append(Tokens.RPAREN)
    if c == '}':
        TOKENS.append(Tokens.RBRACKET)
    if c == '{':
        TOKENS.append(Tokens.LBRACKET)
    if c == '+':
        TOKENS.append(Tokens.PLUS_OPERATOR)
    if c == '-':
        TOKENS.append(Tokens.MINUS_OPERATOR)
    if c == ' ':
        TOKENS.append(Tokens.WHITESPACE)
    if c == ';':
        TOKENS.append(Tokens.SEMICOLON)
    if c == "\"":
        TOKENS.append(Tokens.QUOTATION)
    if c.isalpha() or c.isnumeric():
        curr_string.append(c)
    if not c.isalpha() and not c.isnumeric():
        TOKENS.append("STRING: " + ''.join(curr_string))
        curr_string = []
```

`Tokens` is an enum with the following data:

```
@unique
class Tokens(Enum):
    LPAREN = -1
    RPAREN = -2
    RBRACKET = -3
    LBRACKET = -4
    STRING = -5
    PLUS_OPERATOR = -6
    MINUS_OPERATOR = -7
    INVALID_TOKEN = -8
    WHITESPACE = -9
    SEMICOLON = -10
```

This works mostly correctly, however when iterating through `TOKENS` the following prints out:

```
Tokens.WHITESPACE
STRING: print
Tokens.QUOTATION
STRING: 
Tokens.WHITESPACE
STRING: Hello
Tokens.QUOTATION
STRING: World
Tokens.SEMICOLON
STRING:
```

Why does the console print out a whitespace at the beginning of the array and why does it mix up the order of items being appended to `TOKENS`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: maybe also have a look at using a parser generator? https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER: problem is that you ordered `if` statements incorrectly. Also `if not c.isalpha() and not c.isnumeric():` should be `if not c.isalpha() and not c.isnumeric() and curr_string:`

Let's look at `print "Hello World";` string for example. `code` array will be `['p', 'r', 'i', 'n', 't', ' ', '"', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '"', ';']`. First 5 iterations of loop will end up in:

```
if c.isalpha() or c.isnumeric():
    curr_string.append(c)
```

And sixth iteration, satisfy two `if`'s, first is:

```
if c == ' ':
    TOKENS.append(Tokens.WHITESPACE)
```

And only after than it will append `"STRING: "` to `TOKENS`. To fix that, you need to place `if not c.isalpha() and not c.isnumeric()` at the top of your loop code. Also, `STRING` token is always printed, because you don't check if `curr_string != []`.